# Remove php extension from URL on Windows hosting account using web.config

Tags: url, iis, web-config, seo

I've searched before asking this question. The answered ones were related to Linux hosting account and the ones with Windows hosting account didn't match what I was looking for.

As you might have guessed, I've a Windows shared hosting account with godaddy. My aim was to remove the '.php' extension from the url. After researching I found that .htaccess would do exactly what I want. But I also found that .htaccess doesn't work in Windows environment and that I'll need a web.config file to do the same task.

Now I know there are modules through which the code can be generated, but the problem is I don't know how to get them installed on my hosting account. I don't want to go through the process of contacting the people over at godaddy and hence I'm looking to solve this on my own. What I'm looking for is a web.config equivalent of .htaccess

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

**Current URL : www.abcdef.com/contact.php**

**Desired URL : www.abcdef.com/contact**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Nisar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nisar,

This tutorial does a great job at explaining what you need to do with IIS.

http://atlantawebsites.blogspot.com/2010/06/vanity-urls-with-godaddy-hosting-using.html

Here's what yours would look like:

```
<system.webServer> 
<rewrite> 
    <rules> 
        <rule name="contact"> 
            <match url="http://www.abcdef.com/contact.php" /> 
            <action type="Rewrite" url="http://www.abcdef.com/contact" /> 
        </rule> 
    </rules> 
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Thanks tcole for the quick reply. I went through the link you provided. It's pretty close to what I want. The article shows how to deal with query strings in the url. But that is not the case with me as I'm not dealing with query strings at all.


Also, the code provided by you is setting a rule for a single page (contact.php). Does that mean I'll have to create one rule for each of the pages on my site (home, about, services, portfolio, etc)? I'm hoping there would be a single rule where the condition checks for '.php' extension in all urls and removes them.

Comment: No problem! Were you able to try the sample what I provided?

Comment: Give me a minute, I'll test it out on my server

Comment: Odd. Do you know what version of IIS that your account is on?

Comment: It's IIS 7.0. Also I'm starting to think the problem might be because of overwriting the web.config file. I took your code and created a new web.config file and uploaded it to the root folder. I'm assuming there already was a web.config file on the server (though I could not locate/find it) which got overwritten.

Comment: My bad, was not using correct syntax. 

`<configuration>


<system.webServer> 

<rewrite>

        <rules>
            <rule name="RewritePHP">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.php" />
            </rule>
   
        </rules> 

</rewrite>


</system.webServer> 
</configuration>`